# Problem with POST Request in HTTP Server using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, httpserver

I am trying to simulate the behavior of an API, for this, the first thing I wanted to achieve was to have an HTTP server that works. I am quite new to this. The GET method seems to work, but the POST method is getting complicated and causing errors to pop up. I have tried different things but haven't found a solution. Attached is the code:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import http.server
import socketserver
import json
import cgi
import logging

PORT = 9000

class MyHandler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_HEAD(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "test1")
        self.end_headers()
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "test2")
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        self.end_headers()
        print(self.wfile)
        self.wfile.write(json.dumps({
            "name": "Bob's Home Key",
            "description": "The front door key",
            "notes": "The cleaners come every Monday at 10:00",
            "pickupNote": "Don't mind the dog. He's harmless.",
            "address": {
                "street": "123 Main St.",
                "unit": "1A",
                "city": "Vancouver",
                "stateProv": "BC",
                "country": "Canada",
                "postalCode": "A1A1A1"
            },
            "homeLocation": { "id": 123456 }
        }).encode())

        self.wfile.write(bytes("<p>You accessed path: %s</p>" % self.path,"utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("</body></html>","utf-8"))
        #self.wfile.close()
    def do_POST(self):#potser no va pq no estic tenint en compte que sigui json¿?
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length']) # <--- Gets the size of data
        post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length) # <--- Gets the data itself
        logging.info("POST request,\nPath: %s\nHeaders:\n%s\n\nBody:\n%s\n",
                str(self.path), str(self.headers), post_data.decode('utf-8'))

        self._set_response()
        self.wfile.write("POST request for {}".format(self.path).encode('utf-8'))
   
try:
    server = http.server.HTTPServer(('localhost', PORT), MyHandler)
    print('Started http server')
    server.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('^C received, shutting down server')
    server.socket.close()
```

To test this http server I'm using Insomnia, I don't know if it can affect the process.
The error that i recive is the next:

```
----------------------------------------
Exception occurred during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 51445)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\Python\Python311\Lib\socketserver.py", line 317, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\...\Python\Python311\Lib\socketserver.py", line 348, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\...\Python\Python311\Lib\socketserver.py", line 361, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\...\Python\Python311\Lib\socketserver.py", line 755, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\...\Python\Python311\Lib\http\server.py", line 436, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\...\Python\Python311\Lib\http\server.py", line 424, in handle_one_request
    method()
  File "C:\dev\httpClient\httpClient.py", line 56, in do_POST
    ctype, pdict = cgi.parse_header(self.headers.getheader('content-type'))
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'HTTPMessage' object has no attribute 'getheader'
----------------------------------------
```

I'm new to StackOverflow, so I'm not sure if my question meets the forum's requirements. I've tried to simplify the code as much as possible. If you need anything else, please don't hesitate to let me know. Thank you in advance.